# Custom Stomp Headers using Spring websockets

Tags: java, spring, header, stomp, spring-websocket

I have a basic spring websocket application which currently sends basic data to subscribers.
Currently the system uses the `SimpMessageSendingOperations` class as the message handler.
If I call `SimpMessageSendingOperations.convertAndSend(destination, object)` then the object is converted and received by the subscribed clients.

I would like to be able to send a custom header to the clients.
I have tried using the `SimpMessageSendingOperations.convertAndSend(destination, object, headers)` method to do this.  However the custom header is not included in the stomp message.

Debugging through the code it looks like `StompHeaderAccessor.toStompHeaderMap()` method calls 
`toNativeHeaderMap()` which uses the native header and the original native header maps to build up the stomp headers.

Is there a way to get a custom header added to stomp message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

StompHeaderAccessor extends NativeMessageHeaderAccessor which seems to be where the non-stomp headers live, except they are all stored in a single header called nativeHeaders - which itself is a map.

```
@MessageMapping("/hello")
@SendTo("/topic/greetings")
public  GenericMessage<Greeting> greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {      
    Map<String, List<String>> nativeHeaders = new HashMap<>();
    nativeHeaders.put("hello", Collections.singletonList("world"));

    Map<String,Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put(NativeMessageHeaderAccessor.NATIVE_HEADERS, nativeHeaders);

    return new GenericMessage<Greeting>(new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!"), headers);
}
```

A simple interceptor server-side to wrap your custom headers to the nativeHeaders header should be enough to expose them client-side where they would be available as a map message.headers.nativeHeaders. Simmilarly, you could write a client-side interceptor to move the nativeHeaders into the regular headers - so before your client is aware of the message, all the expected headers are simply in the message.headers.

Comment: Using this I was able to add custom headers by adding a `MessagePostProcessor` parameter to the `convertAndSend` method.  The logic within the overriden `postProcessMessage` then adds the native headers as suggested

Comment: hi Jaimie, could you create a request in JIRA to address this? Although you have found a way to do it, it really shouldn't be that hard to figure out.

Comment: Thanks for You Answer!
Can You also explain how to GET headers which comes with message to server?